# What does Ravaggio mean (in the sense of being evocative of something)?

Tags: word-meaning, name

Ravaggio appears to be an Italian surname, and ravaggio is also listed as a cheese from the Marche region. Can someone tell me more about it (never mind the obvious Caravaggio truncation)?

More precisely, if that name appeared in a historical novel set in XVIIth century Italy, what would be the most likely association in the reader's mind?

Comment: Do you mean "raviggiolo"? And what are you exactly asking?

Comment: Is it an obvious Caravaggio truncation?

Comment: @Charo Please see post update.

Comment: @DaG That's how that name came up to me, then I started wondering if it means anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Italian and to me "Ravaggio" doesn't mean anything at all, it's not suggestive of anything, it's just a sound. Caravaggio on the other hand is the name of a town near Milan, where the painter Michelangelo Merisi was famously born and took his nickname from, and it seems to be related to carrus ("cart/carriage" in Latin) and possibly mean something akin to "place where carts can transit".

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. I was playing with "Caravaggio" to see if I could truncate it and make another name out of it, but that's not working well.

Comment: Can you give a source about the alleged connection with “carrus” of Caravaggio, please? And, about “Ravaggio”,  “just a sound” doesn't mean a lot. If there is an actual family name “Ravaggio”, it must have an origin: families aren't named after “just a sound”.

Comment: @JeanB: Be careful, that isn't an actual answer. As the answerer confirms elsewhere, they don't know the meaning of “Ravaggio”, but this doesn't mean it has no meaning. (I don't know it either, but since there is a Ravaggio family name it has had a meaning for someone somewhere.)

Comment: @DaG You're right. This tells me that naming a character Ravaggio would not trigger anything in people's mind, and that's in fact what I wanted to know. I'll try rephrasing the question accordingly.